# Xcode: ignored symbols warnings while linking for finalizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker

I have problems integrating finalizer to xcode project I get the warnings like this

```
Warning: Ignored symbols were detected in this build. In some cases ignored symbols could cause incorrect finalization. This may be caused by different static libraries containing the same symbol.
warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch armv7)
```

Along with a long list like this

```
Ignored symbol '_int_update' defined at address 0xfb2cc -- it was already defined at 0xd2c94
Ignored symbol '_init' defined at address 0xfcbd8 -- it was already defined at 0xfcba4
Ignored symbol '_update' defined at address 0xfcbe4 -- it was already defined at 0xfcbb0
Ignored symbol '_final' defined at address 0xfcbf0 -- it was already defined at 0xfcbbc
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: And are those symbols defined more than once in the final executable?

Answer (score 0):

If there are 2 or more symbols defined among all the relocatable object files having the same name, the linker will choose one of them and the other symbols are ignored.

If these symbols have different types, it may lead an incomprehensible bug at run-time.

There is an example in chapter 7 of  `Computer Systems_A Programmer-'s Perspective`:

[image]